# C# Retrieve / Get SQL statement from Linq

Tags: linq, datacontext

How can I retrieve the SQL statement from below code in C#.net?

```
Customer _obj = new Customer();

db = new LinqDataContext();               

_obj.name = "name";

db.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(_obj);

db.Customers.Context.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: You can use IQueryable<> to get Query of your LINQ statement but you cant find for Context.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Log](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.log(v=vs.110).aspx) property of DataContext object. Also, it depends on the type of application you are using.

1. For Web Application:-

`db.Log = Response.Output;`

2. For Console Application:-

`db.Log = Console.Out;`

Apart from this you can also use the [GetCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getcommand(v=vs.110).aspx) method of `DataContext` class. `Sql Server Profiler` is again an obvious option.

Comment: Actually I am using Silverlight and the insert function is performed in WCF Service. I wanted to get the SQL statement in the WCF service and insert into another custom log table to record on the records DML.

Comment: @user3607582 - You an simply apply `ToString()` method on the LINQ query, that should give you the generated SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Use sql profile  like this one https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/
where you can see the generated sql.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use SQL Profiler on database, it will give you exact query run by EF on DB.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms181091.aspx

https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/